# add object to a complex json in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Suppose there are two json objects as

1.

```
{
  "conditionTemp": null,
  "value": null,
  "variableValue": "flowParameters_3"
}
```

or

```
{
  "conditionTemp": {
    "functionID": "func_1",
    "parameters": [{}]
  },
  "value": null,
  "variableValue": null
}
```

and

2.

```
{
  "conditionTemp": {
    "functionID": "func_1",
    "parameters": [{
        "conditionTemp": null,
        "value": null,
        "variableValue": "flowParameters_3"
      },
      {
        "conditionTemp": {
          "functionID": "func_1",
          "parameters": [{}]
        },
        "value": null,
        "variableValue": "null"
      },
      {}
    ]
  },
  "value": null,
  "variableValue": null
}
```

i.e
the second object will have ("conditionTemp", "value", "variable"),

the first "conditionTemp" will have "functionID", "parameters"

inside "parameters" we can have any no. of objects. If inside parameters, the the object's "conditionTemp" value is **not null**, we have to check the parameter object inside of that. **If the parameter object is empty, we have to insert the **first object** there.**

So for the above jsons, on adding the first object onto the second,
the resultant json will be

```
{
  "conditionTemp": {
    "functionID": "func_1",
    "parameters": [{
        "conditionTemp": null,
        "value": null,
        "variableValue": "flowParameters_3"
      },
      {
        "conditionTemp": {
          "functionID": "func_1",
          "parameters": [{
                 "conditionTemp": null,
                 "value": null,
                 "variableValue": "flowParameters_3"
           }]
        },
        "value": null,
        "variableValue": "null"
      },
      {}
    ]
  },
  "value": null,
  "variableValue": null
}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: @certainPerformance sorry for the inconvenience, tagged java by mistake

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: @sean how to add the first object into the second object?

Comment: I thought you have answer the question, loop thought the parameter fields, if empty, replace it with the first object

Comment: can you share the required output just for understanding purpose.

Comment: @sean on looping through the parameter fields,  if the conditionTemp value is null, it should get back to the next object in the parameter field and if the object is empty, it should append the object in there. It has to get back to the previous objects unless there is an empty object in any parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

First level would be like this:

```js
var obj_a = {
  "conditionTemp": {
    "functionID": "func_1",
    "parameters": [{
        "conditionTemp": null,
        "value": null,
        "variableValue": "flowParameters_3"
      },
      {
        "conditionTemp": {
          "functionID": "func_1",
          "parameters": [{}]
        },
        "value": null,
        "variableValue": "null"
      },
      {}
    ]
  },
  "value": null,
  "variableValue": null
};

var obj_b = {
  "conditionTemp": null,
  "value": null,
  "variableValue": "flowParameters_3"
};

var final_obj = Object.keys(obj_a).reduce(function(data, key) {
  if (obj_a[key] == null && obj_b[key] != null)
    data[key] = obj_b[key];
  else
    data[key] = obj_a[key];

  return data;
}, {});

console.log(final_obj);
```

Second and further levels would be tricky. Is the format always like that? In your example, values could be (string, null, array of objects)... are there other formats not mentioned or that you wouldn't know?

Comment: Yes, the format will always be the same, and also if conditionTemp is null, then "value" and "variableValue" will have some value, can be string or integers, else they will be null. conditionTemp can be null or object with functionID and parameters.